# Typescript: Can't bind to between since it's not a known property

Tags: angular, typescript

I stumbled upon an issue where a property in my component is not recognized. 
That's my component:

```
import { PrecisionDate } from '../../domain/precision-date';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { DatePrecisionType } from '../../domain/date-precision.type';
import { ValueRange } from '../../domain/value-range';

@Component({
  selector: 'date-control',
  templateUrl: './date-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-control.component.css'],
})
export class DateControlComponent {
  @Input() precision: DatePrecisionType;
  @Input() dateRange: ValueRange<Date>;
  @Input() formControlToUse: FormControl;

  constructor() {}

  get between(): ValueRange<PrecisionDate> {
    return {
      min: this.dateRange ? new PrecisionDate(this.dateRange.min) : null,
      max: this.dateRange ? new PrecisionDate(this.dateRange.max) : null,
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the error thrown:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'between' since it isn't a known property of 'date-input'.
1. If 'date-input' is an Angular component and it has 'between' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'date-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<date-input [ERROR ->][between]="between" [precision]="precision" [formControl]="formControlToUse" > </date-input> "): ng:///UiControlsLibraryModule/DateControlComponent.html@0:15
```

I know that getters and setters are only supported from es5. However, es5 is defined as a target in my tsconfig.json.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Show the HTML file. issue is coming from HTML

Comment: The error is in your template. Can you post it ?

Comment: Your `@Component selector` says `date-control`. Where is `date-input` then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is coming from your html template. Looks like you are trying to use `@Input` which is not defined in your component.

In your `date-input` component you need to add `@Input() between` or remove `[between]="..."` from your html.

Edit. Also check if `date-input` is a component, or you mispelled `date-control` with `date-input` :).

Edit 2. Look at your third point of error. which is

```
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<date-input [ERROR ->][between]="between" [precision]="precision" [formControl]="formControlToUse" > </date-input> "): ng:///UiControlsLibraryModule/DateControlComponent.html@0:15
```

Scroll it a bit, there is a pointer (look for this symbol `[ERROR ->]`) where error occured, this is one of the reason why I love angular, they can point out what is wrong (in most cases of course) :).

Edit 3. I forget about that missing `@Input` can be part of `@Directive` inputs, not only components :).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Meanwhile it turned out that I have forgot to declare my ´@Directive between´. Now it works! Thanks all for your help :) I'll mark your post as answer as it may help others.

Comment: Ach, right, it can be also `@Directive`, i need to correct my answer :)

Comment: Yea, that's what almost drove me crazy as well!